# Change In Cash and Cash Equivalents (cash flow) vs Cash And Cash Equivalents (balance sheet)

Tags: accounting, balance-sheet, cash-flow

**Goal:** Figure out why Change In Cash and Cash Equivalents on the cash flow statement does not equal change in Cash And Cash Equivalents on the balance sheet.

**Example:**

Stock: DEO
Period Ending: 6/30/2016
Period: Annual

**From Cash Flow Statement:**

Change In Cash and Cash Equivalents: 459,000

**From Balance Sheet:**

6/30/2015 Cash And Cash Equivalents: 742,000

6/30/2016 Cash And Cash Equivalents: 1,456,000

Different YOY is 1,456,000  - 742,000 = **714,000**

I would expect YOY difference on the balance sheet to equal the 459,000 on the cash flow statement.  Can anyone explain the disparity.

[Link to Financials](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DEO/financials?p=DEO)

Comment: Following the link you provided, I see different numbers, that still have a disparity. Change in Cash and Cash Equivalents is 427 million for period ending 6/30/2016. Cash & Cash Equivalents balances are 1,089 and 472 million for 2016 & 2015 for a difference of 617 million.

Comment: If you are using Xero (and have a Credit Card account importing), you will need to subtract the amount on your Credit Card account, from the Balance Sheet's ''Total Cash at bank and in hand', in order to see the same amount as is on the 'Cash and Cash Equivalents' on the Cash Flow Statement.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** It's a difference between cash and cash equivalents and **net** cash and cash equivalents.

Download the 2016 annual report from http://www.diageo.com/en-us/investor/Pages/financialreports.aspx

On page 99 is the *Consolidated Statement of Cash Flows* at the bottom is a section "Net cash and cash equivalents consist of:"

`Net cash and cash equivalents consist of: 2016-06-30   2015-06-30

Cash and cash equivalents                      1,089          472
Bank overdrafts                                 (280)         (90)
                                                 809          382`

The difference between net cash of 809 million and 382 million is 427 million, matching the "Change in Cash and Cash Equivalents" from Yahoo.

I do not know that bank overdrafts mean in this situation, but appears to cause cash to show up on balance sheet without being reflected in the net cash portions of the cash flow statement. And the numbers seem like balances, not year of year changes like the rest of the statement of cash flows.

`2015 net CCE              382
2016 cash flow          + 427
                         ----
2016 net CCE              809
Cash from overdrafts    + 280 
                         ----
2015 balance sheet cash 1,089`